# creationComplete event does not show the correct height and width

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, mxml

I have an issue where using MXML, the height and width properties of myBox is correctly acquired but using ActionScript the correct height and width acquired is not correct.

my:Tab extends NavigatorContent (This is NOT the tab in a Tab Bar)
com:myBox extends BorderContainer.

```
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack_main" width="100%" height="100%" creationPolicy="all">                          
 <my:Tab label="My Tab">     
     <s:Scroller  height="100%" width="100%">
     <s:Group height="100%" width="100%">            
        <com:myBox>                                 
        </com:myBox>        
     </s:Group>
     </s:Scroller>       
 </my:Tab>     
</mx:ViewStack>
```

In the **constructor** of **myBox** I set the `percentWidth` and `percentHeight` to both 100.

In the `creationComplete` event of the same myBox, I need to access the `height` and `width`.

This works all ok with the MXML.

However using ActionScript I need to add another tab.

```
var navContainer:Tab = new Tab();
viewstack_main.addElement(navContainer);

var scroller:Scroller = new Scroller();
scroller.percentHeight = 100;
scroller.percentWidth = 100;
navContainer.addElement(scroller);

var grp:Group = new Group();                
grp.percentHeight = 100;
grp.percentWidth = 100;             
scroller.viewport = grp;        

var box:myBox = new myBox();                
grp.addElement(box);
```

But unfortunately, in the creationComplete event of box, the height and width properties are NOT what is expected (the height & width after setting 100%). It is 112.

Any ideas as to why this works with MXML but NOT ActionScript?

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate the display of myBox?

Comment: That is AFTER the creationComplete, is it?

Comment: No it tell the uicomponent to redraw the object on next frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. All I had to do was call `validateSize(false)` before requesting for the height and width.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [initialization sequence in Flex](http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/) in the moment when your `box` is initialized with `creationComplete` parent components are still not fully initialized. In your situation it is better to override `protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void` and use real size from there.

Comment: So if I want to get the actual height and width of the box, I have to do it in the creationComplete event of the Tab? I thought creationComplete event is fired after sizing and everything is done. Or else I will have to listen to parent's creationComplete event from child. Is that possible?

Comment: It strongly depends on for what purpose you want to get size of the tab. Because of even if you get size on Tab's creationComplete user can resize browser window and result will be not so good.

Comment: The size of `Tab` is not required. All I want is the correct size of myBox (because I need to store it somewhere). But as the correct size of myBox is NOT determined until Tab is created, do I have to listen to the Tab's creationComplete?

Comment: Sure, you definitely should try this way.